# Get all packages of project

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I have the name of the project, so i can get the project by

```
IProject project = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject(proj.getName());
IJavaProject jProj = (IJavaProject) project.getNature(JavaCore.NATURE_ID);
```

after I got the project i want to get the names of all the packages in the project.

How can I do it?

Comment: Geez, doesn't Eclipse know how to do this?  Time to upgrade your IDE - get IntelliJ.

Comment: He wants to do it programatically from a Plugin. Would that be so much easier in IntelliJ Idea?

Comment: @duffymo I've been here for a very short time but I can already tell that you really hate Eclipse ^^

Comment: Used to love it - used it for four years and was grateful to have something so good that fit into my employer's budget (zero).  But then I saw IntelliJ, and I've never looked back.  That was seven years ago.  It's only gotten better every year.  Head and shoulders about all other IDEs, including Visual Studio.

Comment: @SPF - absolutely.  Everything is easier in IntelliJ.  I don't need all those plug-ins, because it's integrated better and it reads my mind.

Comment: @duffymo I use both. IntelliJ has more power in many ways, but Eclipse is much better when it comes to usability (and of course it has better Spring integration)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in Rhino, can I enumerate the list of available Java packages? How?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777059/in-rhino-can-i-enumerate-the-list-of-available-java-packages-how)